# Android go to an activity the second time after onbackpressed() one time not working?

Tags: android

I have a problem with going to an activity at the second time. Consume I have Activity A with a button and a textview. textview show number of image in activity B. When I click on button it goes to Activity B. B has a gridview to show image. At first time go to B everything is okay: gridview load image normally. Then in activity B I press back button to back to Activity A. Then I click the button again to go to activity B. Problem is in the second time go to B it's not working. No data loaded for gridview in B. And when I back to A textview show null.

I don't know why this happens.

Comment: post your code so people can understand your issue

Comment: @RaviRupareliya tks a lot I found my problem. I have a lot Intent to an activity and I catch the wrong one. Tks very much :)))